# can cloudwatch send metrics in less than 1 min?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

AWS documentation states cloudwatch shares metrics every one minute, is it possible to get the metrics checked every 10 secs or less than a minute? If an instance goes down and I have to wait a full 1 minute to know that it is down?  To spin up a new one in its place?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are referring to **Amazon EC2 metrics** that are collected by Amazon CloudWatch.

No, you cannot configure these metrics to be collected more often. By default, Amazon EC2 metrics are collected every **five minutes**. You can activate **detailed monitoring** to obtain the metrics every **one minute**.

However, **Elastic Load Balancing health checks** can check the health of an instance more often, and it will only send traffic to instances that are responding correctly to health checks.

**Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling** can be configured to use Elastic Load Balancing health checks to determine the health of instances. If an instance is identified as *unhealthy*, Auto Scaling will automatically replace the instance. However, this can take several minutes to be identified and have a new instance operational. Thus, it is recommended to always be running a **minimum of two instances**.

Comment: Auto scaling is something my customer is not interested! So, if my infra has 5 instances running and if one goes down, will there be an immediate notification? or I should wait for the cloud watch to send me the metrics in normal course ? 
If an instance goes down, I want to replicate it using Ansible scripts (build an instance, install my app stack etc), so How would I identify immediately if an instance goes down?

Comment: Auto Scaling has two capabilities: Changing the quantity of EC2 instances based upon demand, and maintaining a given number of instances by automatically replacing instances that fail. So, you should consider using Auto Scaling for this second capability, since it will can  monitor the status of servers and launch replacements without any additional coding!

Comment: You can create alarms in Amazon CloudWatch that can send a notification, but that will only be in response to a change in metrics stored in Amazon CloudWatch. If you want to react faster than CloudWatch, you would need to create your own monitoring system. However, given that you have five instances, the other instances should be able to handle the load for a period of time until new servers are created, so you probably don't need a sub-minute response time. But, that's up to you!